Intersection of an uncountable set and an uncountable dense set
Question :

Let $A,B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ with $A$ being uncountable and $B$ being uncountable and dense.
Must it be true that $A\cap B≠\emptyset?$

Since $(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})\cap\mathbb{Q}=\emptyset,$ we have that the intersection of an uncountable set and a countable dense set may be empty.
Since $(-\infty,0)\cap(0,\infty)=\emptyset,$ we have that the intersection of an uncountable set and an uncountable (but non-dense) set may also be empty.
So, it is clear that we need to make use of both the uncountability and the density of $B.$
I don't know where to go from here. From what I saw when I looked this up, this might require topology to show. However, I don't know any topology.
Is this statement true? Is there any elementary-ish way to see this?

$A$ Cantor's set, $B=\Bbb R\setminus A$.

Nothing can be said about $A\cap B$ from that information. I believe that any set $S\subset\mathbb R$ can be written as $A\cap B$ for some pair of uncountable sets $A,B$ with $B$ dense.

Great insight @DarkMalthorp! Indeed if $S$ is uncountable then $A=S$, $B=\Bbb R$ works; if $S$ is countable, then $\Bbb R\setminus(S\cup\Bbb Q)$ is uncountable and can be written as the disjoint union of two uncountable sets $A_0$ and $B_0$, and then we can take $A=S\cup A_0$ and $B=S\cup\Bbb Q\cup B_0$.

I think that $A=(-\infty,0)\cap(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})$ and $B=(0,\infty)\cup(Q\cap(-\infty,0))$ should disprove your question.
Similarly, I think it isn't true even when you ask $A$ to be uncountable and dense by taking $A$ as the union of the set of rational numbers in $(-\infty,0)$ and the set of irrational numbers in $(0,\infty)$ and then taking $B$ the same but changing the order of rational and irrational.
